# UEFI firmware resetting bootorder

Tags: boot, uefi, firmware

I am trying to boot Fedora 23 that I have just installed on a laptop, replacing Windows. I just can't boot it. I kept the UEFI boot partition but replaced all the other partitions with Linux ones. The problems are:

1. Fedora is in the list when I run `efibootmgr` and I can put it first in the boot order, but when I reboot, the firmware ignores the boot order and tries to boot Windows first, and also resets the boot order. I can stop it from trying to boot windows by removing the Windows boot loader, but then it tries to boot the next items on the boot order and skips the installed Fedora (possibly because by that point, I'm guessing, the boot order has already been reset). This is very suspicious.
2. In the firmware settings, under Settings -> General -> Boot Sequence, Fedora doesn't show up, even though it shows up in `efibootmgr`. If I try to add it manually, 2 disks show up in the UI, but they seem to both be duplicate copies of the USB stick - they are exactly the same as each other and they contain the same files that are on the USB stick, including one of my personal files that I put on there.
3. Setting the next boot OS with `efibootmgr -n` also doesn't work. If I run `efibootmgr` again immediately after running that command, it shows the changed settings, so it doesn't look like it's failed to write them.

P.S. Because I have removed the Windows boot loader, if I remove the USB stick and reboot, the laptop then goes into Dell SupportAssist mode.

Comment: Did you install Fedora from an [EFI shim aware disk](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/sect-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-Implementation_of_UEFI_Secure_Boot-Shim.html)?

Comment: Sure you do not have two ESPs?   Can you get to a UEFI shell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a firmware bug. I finally worked around it by:

1. Deleting the `Microsoft` directory in `/boot/efi/EFI` and replacing it with the contents of the Fedora directory (note: this assumes you don't want to dual boot with Windows, which I don't).
2. Copying the grub `.efi` file into where the firmware expected to find the Windows boot loader.

Note: The above two steps still didn't make it boot automatically when the USB stick was inserted for some reason, but even when the USB stick was inserted, I could still select Grub by pressing F12 on boot up.

Comment: There is not normally a Windows directory in the ESP.   Typically there is a Microsoft directory and the Microsoft boot loader is located at ../Microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi.   If you want GRUB2 to be your only bootloader,  install it as BOOTX64.EFI (assuming you have an IA64 platform)

Answer (score 0):

It is also probably resulted by a setting called "**Boot Order Lock**" in BIOS.

You can easily turn that off in BIOS, normally in the "Security" section or "Start up" section.

Once the "Boot Order Lock" is on, not only the order is fixed, but the changes to existing boot entries' EFI files will not take effect as well. People tend to forget to change this option.