# Can't mount Windows partition in Linux - hibernated, refuses to mount

Tags: mount, grub2, dual-boot

I've disabled all of the secure-boot options (secure boot, legacy boot, fastboot, & even the one in windows which I had to go to power settings & change from hibernation to shutting down).

Here's the error if it'll help:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/%Username/Windows: Command-line
`mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000"
"/dev/sda4" "/media/%Username/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit
status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount
'/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount
option.
```

I read online that this is a HP BIOS problem but not one of those posts actually showed how to fix the problem so I though I'd ask myself.

Comment: This is really two problems in one question. Your answer has nothing to do with the first question, which is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289527/uefi-firmware-resetting-bootorder

Comment: @RobinGreen It is not a duplicate. Please see the `man ntfs-3g` , the `remove_hiberfile` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the recommended terminal commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda4 /media/windows
```

it doesn't really do anything bad to the windows partition just allows you to read and write the disk, you might have to write the second command every time you boot to windows and then back to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/partition_name
```